# Login with facebook using DotNetOpenAuth 4.0

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I have created an app in facebook and got facebookappid and secret.  I am using these id and secret in example that came with DotNetOpenAuth Library.  Instead of redirecting facebook login page, it give me 400(Bad Request) error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the latest DNOA 4.0 CTP, Facebook is incompatible with it because it implements an older draft of OAuth 2.0

Comment: Is this still true? As of 2012-10-26?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. FB sees the downside of breaking compatibility with existing clients to be worse than maintaining an implementation of an outdated spec.