# DotNetOpenAuth Facebook Integration ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I have been trying to integrate Facebook Login based on the sample code provided by DNOA but i have been unsuccessful.

Here is what i have done:

1. Imported the latest DNOA packages via NuGet Package Manager(v4.3.3.13295).
2. I have setup a Facebook Dev account and testing app, importing the relevant keys into my webconfig.
3. I have integrated the facebook login code into the membership provider and all works well.

The problem arrises when i call the below code again after Facebook redirects back to my site:
IAuthorizationState authorization = fbClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

I get an error saying:
400(Bad Request)

After reading around on the net i have found the following:
"If you're using the latest DNOA 4.0 CTP, Facebook is incompatible with it because it implements an older draft of OAuth 2.0"
from: [Login with facebook using DotNetOpenAuth 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112595/login-with-facebook-using-dotnetopenauth-4-0)

Can anyone confirm that this is the case and if so can you please provide me with a link to an older version that works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to never call

IAuthorizationState authorization = fbClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

more than once.